# 'Force' magento-init block to execute?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, magento2

I have very little experience with Magento2, but am striking a problem that potentially requires some insight from somebody who does.

I only have front-end access.

I am including the following `magento-init` block:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*":
        {
            "Magento_Customer\/js\/customer-data":
            {
                "sectionLoadUrl": "http:\/\/www.example.com\/customer\/section\/load\/",
                "cookieLifeTime": "3600",
                "updateSessionUrl": "http:\/\/www.example.com\/customer\/account\/updateSession\/"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

in the `body` of my page, which I would expect to populate a `sectionLoadUrl` under `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data`.

Just before my closing `</body>` tag, I include a file which executes the following function:

```
function highlightWishlistHearts() {
    require(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function(customerData) {
        customerData.reload(['wishlist'], false).complete(function(response) {
            var customerWishlist = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText).wishlist.items;
            for (var i = 0, wishlistLength = customerWishlist.length; i < wishlistLength; i++) {
                var productURL = customerWishlist[i].product_url;
                jQuery('.product-item-actions').each(function() {
                    if (productURL === jQuery(this).data('product-url')) {
                        jQuery(this).children('.towishlist.remove').addClass('inwishlist');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The purpose of this function is to add a class to those products on the page that belong to the user's wishlist.

However, this throws a console error, specifying that `sectionLoadUrl is undefined`. If I instead call the function from inside a `setTimeout`, it executes as I would expect, after the specified timeout of 5s.

I want to avoid using a `setTimeout`, so would encourage any ideas around how I can resolve this issue. Is there perhaps a way to force the `magento-init` block to be executed when it is defined? Is there perhaps another dependency I could add to my `require` block that would force this to wait a sufficient length of time? Is there more that I need to be considering? I have tried including the `magento-init` block in the `head` of the page, but didn't see any better of a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found that the `reload()` function was making a request to http://www.example.com/customer/section/load/?sections=wishlist&update_section_id=false, so I instead performed an AJAX request to this page, and read from the JSON on there. Got rid of the `setTimeout`, as was desired.